# JsonConvert a json with a list<> element WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a json coming from webservice, which has a List<> element in it.
But when I try to deserialize it using Newtonsoft.Json

```
Response resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(responseStr);
```

then when I fetch the list using resp.ProjectList, it throws a null pointer exception.
So the `List<Project>` is not getting deserialized.
Any idea what am I missing?

The response is of the form:

```
public Response 
{
    public string msg;
    public List<Project> ProjectList{get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class Project
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ID {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: The following is the json :{
    "Msg": "Success",
    "ProjectList": [
        {
            "ID": "/Date(1400120100000-0700)/"
        },
        {
            "ID": "/Date(1404260520000-0700)/"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes, they do not mix well with Json.NET.

Or you can do the deserialization "manually"

```
var j = JToken.Parse("{ \"Msg\": \"Success\", \"ProjectList\": [ { \"ID\": \"/Date(1400120100000-0700)/\" }, { \"ID\": \"/Date(1404260520000-0700)/\" } ] } ");
var resp = new Response
{
    msg = j.SelectToken("Msg").ToString(),
    ProjectList = ((JArray) j.SelectToken("ProjectList")).Select(l => new Project {ID = l.SelectToken("ID").ToString()}).ToList()
};
```

Comment: I have received the datacontracts from a different team, so I have a dll and cannot make changes to it.

Comment: Using manual parsing did work, but when I tried running the same piece of code on visual studio 13, with the same version of newtonsoft, it worked!
Any idea is it because of the IDE version(since the code nd version of json convertor lib is same) or something I might be missing?